# Using fn:path() to select an element in XML

Tags: xpath

I have an XML with a HTML-like structure:

```
         <h1 id="1">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h1>
        <h1 id="2">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>translated text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h1>
```

I want to copy the text from nodes in `h1 id="2"` to the node that's at the same position in `h1 id="1"`.

Required result:

```
<p>text/translated text</p>
```

I can create an Xpath that addresses a single node:
/h1[2]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/p[1]

but I can't figure out how to create an xPath that finds "the node in `h1 id="2"` that's at the same position as the node I'm working on in `h1 id="1"`"
i.e. when I'm in

```
/h1[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/p[1]
```

I want to address

```
/h1[2]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/p[1]
```

and also

```
/h1[3]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/p[1]
```

etc. if more h1 elements are present in the XML.

I tried using the path() function. This returns the path of the current node:

```
/h1[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/p[1]
```

I'll modify this string by replacing the first part:

```
<xsl:variable name="newpath" select="concat('/Q{}h1[1]', substring-after(path(),'/Q{}h1[2]'))">
```

and then read the contents of that xPath:

<xsl:apply-templates select="$newpath"/>

this fails because $newpath is seen as a string instead of a path.

How can I get the output of path() to be treated as a node set instead of a string?

Comment: Well, if you want to evaluate an XPath you have as a string then you need `xsl:evaluate` e.g. `<xsl:evaluate context-item="/" xpath="$newpath"/>` e.g. `<xsl:variable name="other-element" as="item()*"><xsl:evaluate context-item="/" xpath="$newpath"/></xsl:variable> <xsl:apply-templates select="$other-element"/>`. Whether that is necessary I kind of doubt, if you know you want to process `/h1[2]`, `/h1[3]` it looks like you don't need dynamic XPath evaluation and string construction of paths.

Comment: I oversimplified my example: I don't have a single `<p>` to process, I have an entire chapter containing a few hundred `<p>`, and each `<p>` from `h1 id=2` must be copied to the corresponding `p` in `h1 id=1`

Comment: I don't know what to answer to that comment, if you have a string with an XPath expression, whether it selects a single node or elements or hundreds, if you want to evaluate that string as an XPath you need XSLT 3.0 `xsl:evaluate` (available in SaxonJS 2, Saxon Java/.NET HE 10 and later, Saxon C HE 11, Saxon Java 9.8 PE/EE and later, SaxonCS).

Comment: your comment solved my problem: when I use xsl:evaluate I get the results I'm looking for, so I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically evaluate an XPath expression you have as a string, in XSLT 3 and where `xsl:evaluate` is supported (Saxon PE/EE 9.8 and later, Saxon HE 10 and later, SaxonJS 2 and later, Altova XML 2017 R3 and later) you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:evaluate context-item="/" xpath="$newpath"/>
```

to select and output the element(s) selected by `$newpath` or you can of course store the result of `xsl:evaluate` in a variable and push the nodes to apply-templates with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="nodes" as="item()*"><xsl:evaluate context-item="/" xpath="$newpath"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$nodes"/>
```

[Online sample using SaxonJS](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xpath-default-namespace%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22h1%5B%40id%20%3D%20%271%27%5D%2F%2Fp%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3Ex%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22newpath%22%20select%3D%22replace%28path%28%29%2C%20%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%7Dh1%5B1%5D%27%2C%20%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%7Dh1%5B2%5D%27%2C%20%27q%27%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aevaluate%20context-item%3D%22%2F%22%20xpath%3D%22%24newpath%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Ch1%20id%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3Etext%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fh1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%20id%3D%222%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Cp%3Etranslated%20text%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fh1%3E&input-type=HTML).